Github showing My Computer authored and My Computer committed to a repository but it should only show User committed for new repository
Github shows that my computer is authoring and also committing to a GitHub repository that I made when it should only just show my account. I got a new computer in the past year so maybe I mistakenly misconfigured something.
This is what my commits look like:


This is what my commits should look like:


I don't know why it's showing "My Computer and My Computer {commit message}" when it should show "user {commit message}". I want to make sure that I'm publishing under my GitHub account.
What I did: I made a brand new git repository that is completely empty from the Github website. Then I went to that directory in my local machine (cd/Desktop/ExampleDirectory) and executed the following commands:
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/example/example.git
git push -u origin main

My code pushed to the newly created repository fine without problems, but it's not publishing under my Github account. The commit should be published as "{Github User} {commit message}" on Github, except it shows "{my computer name} and {my computer name} {commit message}".
